# Cannot access Seagate Central 4TB NAS from Windows 8.1 laptop

Tags: windows-8, crashplan-central

I cannot access the Seagate Central 4TB NAS from my Windows 8.1 laptop.

It sees that it is there, but then a window displays with the message:

> Windows cannot access Seagate-XXXXX. Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found.

I can access the Seagate Central NAS from my Windows 7 desktop with no problem.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Can you access it from other computer? What you can't access, web interface, SMB share?

Comment: I cannot access the Seagate Central NAS from my Windows 8.1 laptop.  It is sees that it is there, but then a window displays with the message: "Windows cannot access \\Seagate-XXXXX.  Error code: 0x80070035 The network path was not found."  I can access the Seagate Central NAS from my Windows 7 desktop with no problem.  Sorry for not being more detailed.

Comment: Have you try to access it via IP address instead of SMB hostname?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to clear your saved credentials out of Credential Manager in Control Panel.

Go to Control Panel > User Accounts and Family Safety (if you're in Category view) > Credential Manager then select Windows Credentials and look for saved credentials the same as the login name used for the Seagate NAS web interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same irritating problem

the only way i have found around that is to:

download and run the Seagate discovery tool

find the new drives located amongst the other drives.

hope that helped you

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows x64 the TCP/IP Netbios Helper was disabled (might be a standard thing, while MS wants to promote the Homegroup function?). Once I started this service, I immediately had access again to the DS.

In order to check this go to and double click on:
- Control Panel
- Administrative Tools
- Services
- TCP/IP Netbios Helper
- Change Startup tÿpe: disabled -> automatic
- Under Service status click start

Answer (score 0):

Ive had the same issue and after several forums and tech support etc, my issue (most likely yours as well) is the the obsolete smbv1 protocol. my nass will appear by dlna on tvs etc and on my network but i cant access the files. the easiest way to check if this is your issue, is to follow this instructions

http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/005532en?language=en_US#Connecting to the drive with Windows:

basically go the RUN command type \YOURNASIPADDRESS and enter, if you get the SMB1 error then as far as i can tell you as well as I my friend are screwed

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows 10.  I went into Control Panel>>Programs and Features and select Add/Remove Windows features from the side menu.  SMBv1 is shown there as not active so just click to put a tick next to it and select ok.  That should sort the problem. (It may need to reboot as well)
Jonno

Answer (score 0):

For me some required windows services were not running. Starting them fixed the problem. Here are the steps I took which [I found here](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2927231/problems-setting-dashboard-seagate-personal-cloud.html):

There are two things we need to check. First, please verify the following Microsoft services are started and automatic:

- Service             Service Status        Startup Type
- COM+ Event System    Started              Automatic
- COM+ System Application  Started          Automatic
- Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider  Started Automatic
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)  Started      Automatic
- Seagate Dashboard Service    Started      Automatic
- Seagate Mobile Backup Service    Started  Automatic
- System Event Notification    Started      Automatic
- Task Scheduler        Started             Automatic
- Volume Shadow Copy    Started             Automatic
- Windows Event Log     Started             Automatic

To open Windows Services, Run services.msc to open the Services Manager. Here you will be able to start, stop, disable, delay Windows Services. Right-click on your Start button to open the WinX Menu. Select Run. This opens the Run box. Now type services.msc in it and hit Enter to open the Services Manager.

Secondly, the Seagate Dashboard software requires the following Windows prerequisites. To check this, open control panel In the search box on the taskbar, type control panel, and then select Control Panel. Then in the search panel type programs and hit enter. Make sure the following programs are installed on your system.

For 64-bit Windows operating system:

Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable (x86) 
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable(x64)
Microsoft .NET 4.0
Windows Installer 3.1

For 32-bit Windows operating system:

Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable (x86)
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable (x86) 
Microsoft .NET 4.0
Windows Installer 3.1

To check whether you’re using a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 10, open the Settings app by pressing Windows+I, and then head to System > About. On the right side, look for the “System type” entry. It will show you two pieces of information—whether you’re using a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system and whether you have a 64-bit capable processor.

Answer (score 0):

No one is screwed, Windows Updates unchecks a box in the system settings. Just check it back and reboot.
Go to> Control Panel>Programs and Features>Turn Windows Features On or Off
Scroll down and make sure that SMB1.0 and SMB Direct are checked.
Reboot
You should be good.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub5Rx.jpg)